# Cannot install Laravel on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, laravel

i tried to install laravel 4.2 on ubuntu 12.04.but when i try i get the following error.I used xammp latest version  which contains php 5.6

```
 Problem 1
- laravel/framework v4.2.9 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found.
- laravel/framework v4.2.8 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found
```

Comment: plz give me answer instead of reducing mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible problem is that when you're installing laravel composer or something else uses system php package (which on ubuntu 12.04 could be older than 5.4). 
Try

```
php --version
```

If it's the deal, you can try somehow force composer to use php from xampp. Don't know where it's on your system, on my archlinux it's in /opt/lampp/bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

Install Apache PHP and Mysql individually

install apache

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

install php5

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt
```

install mysql server and client

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server && apt-get install mysql-client
```

install phpmyadmin for database administration

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

enable php5-mcrypt and mod rewrite

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Install composer

```
cd ~
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Install Laravel

```
cd /var/www
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project --prefer-dist
```

Setup your apache virtual host

```
# Copy default Apache conf
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default /etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel.conf
# Edit laravel.conf and change DocumentRoot to /var/www/laravel/public
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/laravel.conf
# Edit laravel.conf add the following and save.
DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public
<Directory /var/www/laravel/public>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
# Reload Apache
sudo service apache2 reload
# Disable default Apache conf
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
# Enable laravel.conf
sudo a2ensite laravel.conf
# Reload Apache
sudo service apache reload
```

Comment: i install xampp correctlyand it has php 5.6 .so why cant i do that in xammp

Comment: if you were on windows and running WAMP that sounds ok because setting up php on windows is sometimes pain in ass but in linux you have everything you need why use xampp